# iOS: Why UIView's drawRect has better performance than CALayer's drawInContext

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, drawrect

I am currently learning drawing with UIView and CALayer. I quickly did a drawing app to experiment with the two classes. I noticed CALayer had worse performance than UIView. Here is the code:

myView.m

```
@interface myView()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *background;

#ifdef USE_LAYER
@property (nonatomic, strong) drawingLayer *drawCanvas;
#else
@property (nonatomic, strong) drawingView  *drawCanvas;
#endif
@end

@implementation myView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        self.background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self addSubview:self.background];
#ifdef USE_LAYER
        self.drawCanvas = [[drawingLayer alloc] init];
        self.drawCanvas.frame = frame;
        [self.layer addSublayer:self.drawCanvas];
#else
        self.drawCanvas = [[drawingView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self.drawCanvas.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:self.drawCanvas];
#endif
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGPoint)getPoint:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches
{
    NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
    UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touchesArray objectAtIndex:0];
    return [touch locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint point = [self getPoint:touches];
    self.drawCanvas.points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.drawCanvas.startPoint = point;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint point = [self getPoint:touches];
    [self.drawCanvas.points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
    self.background.image = [self imageFromLayer:self.layer];
    self.drawCanvas.points = nil;
    [self.drawCanvas setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint point = [self getPoint:touches];
    [self.drawCanvas.points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
    [self.drawCanvas setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return outputImage;
}

@end
```

drawingView.h

```
@interface drawingView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint startPoint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *points;

@end
```

drawingView.m

```
@implementation drawingView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

     CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);
     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.startPoint.x, self.startPoint.y);

     for (NSValue *point in self.points)
     {
         CGPoint location = [point CGPointValue];
         CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, location.x, location.y);
     }
     CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

@end
```

I also have "drawingLayer" which is essentially the same thing as "drawingView", except it a subclass of CALayer and does the same drawing in "drawInContext".

What I found was the drawRect has much better performance, the drawing is almost in-sync with the touch position, with very minor lag.
Why is this the case? I expected the CALayer drawing to be at least the same, if not better. In fact, someone told me today that drawing in CALayer is hardware-accelerated, which is the preferred way if performance is a concern. Certainly this is NOT the case in my little experiment. Why?

Comment: CALayer animations can make it appear slower in movement. Maybe that's what you're observing

Comment: Do you feel like it is slower, or it really is? Have you used Instruments to verify this? Besides, have you tried updating the cgPath of a CAShapeLayer instead? This might boost the performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by CALayer's default animation.

Try to override the `action(forKey event: String) -> CAAction?` and always return `nil` while subclassing the CALayer Class